# Maximum value of border rank

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, tensor-rank

I have to prove that $\max\limits_{t \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m\times k}} brk (t) \ge \max(\min(n, mk), \min(m, nk), \min(k, nm))$, where $brk(t)$ is the border rank of $t$.

I suppose that it is well-known statement but I am just starting to learn tensors and do not know how to prove this. Of course because of symmetry it is sufficient to prove that $\max\limits_{t \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m\times k}} brk (t) \ge \min(n, mk)$. Maybe we can just give an example of such sequence?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1908747/proof-that-multilinear-rank-of-tensor-less-of-equal-than-border-rank/1908833#1908833

Comment: @Ignat, OK I got it. We can just take a matrix $n \times mk$ with the full rank of columns (or rows depends which is less) and build tensor. Than $rk_1(t) = \min(n, mk) \le brk(t)$. Thank you!